# Strange behaviours on PHP MYSQL image unlink

Tags: php, mysql, image, unlink

I have followed several tutorials on here and I can't figure out my mistake.

The Gallery gets displayed correctly, and the check boxes have the right value when I check with Element inspector in Firefox, but this little script I wrote always unlinks the last picture in the loop, and the Database row does not get deleted.

Maybe you have a better eye for what I am missing then myself?

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM  houses ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo $result['title'] . $result['id'];
echo"<br>";
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE photo_category=" . $result['id'];
$query1 = mysql_query($sql1);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $photo_filename = $row['photo_filename'];

    echo "<form action='' method='post'>
        <li style='float:left; list-style-type:none;'>
        <img src='houses/" . $photo_filename . "' title='$photo_filename' width='100px'> &nbsp; 
        <input type='checkbox' name='delete' value='$photo_filename'/> <br> 
            </li> ";
}

echo "<p style='clear:both' /> <input type='submit'  value='Delete Selected' />";
echo" </form>";
echo "<p style='clear:both;'>";
echo "<br><br>";
}

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && is_array($_POST['delete']) && count($_POST['delete']) > 0) {
unlink("THIS/IS/A/WORKING/PATH/houses/" . $photo_filename);
unlink("THIS/IS/A/WORKING/PATH/houses/tb_" . $photo_filename);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM gallery_photos WHERE photo_filename = $photo_filename");
}
?>
```

Comment: You are not closing your `form` element, thus generating invalid HTML.

Comment: This code is **INCREDIBLY** dangerous, and you should stop working on it until you've learned why... consider `$photo_filename = '../../../../../../windows/system32/ntoskrnl.exe'`

Comment: @CBroe Sorry about the unclosed form, deleted it by accident while adjusting the side space, so it would be displayed in the code bracket :P

Comment: @MarcB The security measures are taken somewhere else, but focus on what I am asking for, not on the security holes :P I will close then once I know the exact functionality!

Comment: does this not create an error message?

Comment: Funny enough it only complains that it cannot unlink an Image, but this because it has already removed it, but the DB entry is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the  element each time for the new photo, but the submit button and only one closing tag are outside all of the forms. You may want to fix the html to have this working properly.

**EDIT**:
**The wrong file gets deleted, because you're using `$photo_filename` variable in the last 3 rows instead of the value from `$_POST['delete']`.**

Side note: this code is really awful and buggy. It's a security nightmare.

Comment: This is just a test version, I need to know what my delete functions needs to accomplish(meaning what elements it needs), before I can write a version that is suited to security standards...

Comment: As I said, you're using `$photo_filename` variable when deleting, not the value from the form!

Answer (score 0):

something like this should sort it, I have not tested it but hopefully it will work.

```
foreach ($_POST['delete'] as $filename) {
   unlink("THIS/IS/A/WORKING/PATH/houses/" . $filename);
   unlink("THIS/IS/A/WORKING/PATH/houses/tb_" . $filename);
   mysql_query("DELETE FROM gallery_photos WHERE photo_filename = $filename");
}

echo '<form action='' method='post'>';
$sql = "SELECT id, title FROM  houses ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $result['title'] . $result['id'];
    echo"<br>";
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE photo_category=" . $result['id'];
    $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
        $photo_filename = $row['photo_filename'];

        echo "<li style='float:left; list-style-type:none;'>
            <img src='houses/" . $photo_filename . "' title='$photo_filename' width='100px'> &nbsp; 
            <input type='checkbox' name='delete[]' value='$photo_filename'/> <br> 
                </li> ";

    }

    echo "<p style='clear:both' /> <input type='submit'  value='Delete Selected' />";
    echo" </form>";
    echo "<p style='clear:both;'>";
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

notice the [] at the end of the checkbox name, this means that it will create an array of them. You might want to add an additional check around the foreach to prevent it running if the $_POST['delete'] has not been set.

Answer (score 0):

First, just to be sure, you are getting the params, you can use:

```
echo "<br />Contents of \$_POST:<br />";
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
      echo "   $k = $v<br />";
}
```

So you know what params are you getting. And it looks like working.

Also, you can use it, to delete the images,

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) :
   if ( $k == "delete" ) :
      // add your code for unlink and delete
   endif;
endforeach;
```

Second, check for permissions before to delete

```
chmod($this->uploaddir . $this->finalName, octdec(0777)); // Maybe 0666 is enough
@unlink( path_to_file ); // @ to avoid see code errors
```

And just, for you consideration, maybe if you use  you don't have to be taking care about float, and clearing

Cheers